# ros-mpu9150: CMakeLists.txt undefined reference

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying create a ROS node that publishes the InvenSense MPU-9150 data into a Topic. I'm using the userspace driver **linux-mpu9150**.

Here's the file structure of the package:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cscope.out
├── include
├── LICENSE
├── package.xml
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── linux-mpu9150
    │   ├── eMPL
    │   │   ├── dmpKey.h
    │   │   ├── dmpmap.h
    │   │   ├── inv_mpu.c
    │   │   ├── inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver.c
    │   │   ├── inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver.h
    │   │   ├── inv_mpu.h
    │   │   └── README.md
    │   ├── glue
    │   │   ├── linux_glue.c
    │   │   └── linux_glue.h
    │   ├── imu.c
    │   ├── imucal.c
    │   ├── LICENSE
    │   ├── local_defaults.h
    │   ├── Makefile-cross
    │   ├── Makefile-native
    │   ├── mpu9150
    │   │   ├── mpu9150.c
    │   │   ├── mpu9150.h
    │   │   ├── quaternion.c
    │   │   ├── quaternion.h
    │   │   ├── vector3d.c
    │   │   └── vector3d.h
    │   └── README.md
    ├── mpu9150_node.cpp
    └── random.cpp
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(ros_mpu9150)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs)

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES mpu9150
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

## Alternatively we can use the CMakeLists.txt of the subdirs
#add_subdirectory(src/linux-mpu9150)

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  src/linux-mpu9150
  src/linux-mpu9150/eMPL
  src/linux-mpu9150/glue
  src/linux-mpu9150/mpu9150
)

#link_directories()


# Test to verify simple ROS node
add_executable(random src/random.cpp)
target_link_libraries(random ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )

# The MPU9150 node

# Adds flags to the compiler command line for sources in the current directory and below.
add_definitions(-DEMPL_TARGET_LINUX -DMPU9150 -DAK8975_SECONDARY)

add_executable(mpu9150_node src/mpu9150_node.cpp)
add_library(mpu9150 SHARED src/linux-mpu9150/mpu9150/mpu9150.h src/linux-mpu9150/mpu9150/mpu9150.c)
add_library(quaternion SHARED src/linux-mpu9150/mpu9150/quaternion.h src/linux-mpu9150/mpu9150/quaternion.c)
add_library(vector3d SHARED src/linux-mpu9150/mpu9150/vector3d.h src/linux-mpu9150/mpu9150/vector3d.c)
add_library(inv_mpu SHARED src/linux-mpu9150/eMPL/inv_mpu.h src/linux-mpu9150/eMPL/inv_mpu.c)
add_library(inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver SHARED src/linux-mpu9150/eMPL/inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver.h src/linux-mpu9150/eMPL/inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver.c)
add_library(linux_glue SHARED src/linux-mpu9150/glue/linux_glue.h src/linux-mpu9150/glue/linux_glue.c)

target_link_libraries(mpu9150_node mpu9150 inv_mpu quaternion linux_glue inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver vector3d ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
#target_link_libraries(mpu9150_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

And what i got when i execute `catkin_make`:

```
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/victor/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 12%] Built target beginner_tutorials_gencpp
[ 25%] Built target beginner_tutorials_genlisp
[ 50%] Built target beginner_tutorials_genpy
[ 56%] Built target inv_mpu
[ 62%] [ 68%] Built target inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver
Built target linux_glue
[ 75%] Built target mpu9150
[ 81%] [ 87%] Built target random
Built target quaternion
[ 93%] Scanning dependencies of target mpu9150_node
Built target vector3d
[100%] Building CXX object ros_mpu9150/CMakeFiles/mpu9150_node.dir/src/mpu9150_node.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/victor/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ros_mpu9150/mpu9150_node
CMakeFiles/mpu9150_node.dir/src/mpu9150_node.cpp.o: In function `main':
mpu9150_node.cpp:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `mpu9150_set_debug(int)'
mpu9150_node.cpp:(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `mpu9150_init(int, int, int)'
mpu9150_node.cpp:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `linux_delay_ms(unsigned long)'
mpu9150_node.cpp:(.text+0x28f): undefined reference to `mpu9150_read(mpudata_t*)'
mpu9150_node.cpp:(.text+0x4b5): undefined reference to `linux_delay_ms(unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/mpu9150_node.dir/src/mpu9150_node.cpp.o: In function `set_cal(int, char*)':
mpu9150_node.cpp:(.text+0x97e): undefined reference to `mpu9150_set_mag_cal(caldata_t*)'
mpu9150_node.cpp:(.text+0x98b): undefined reference to `mpu9150_set_accel_cal(caldata_t*)'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make[2]: *** [/home/victor/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ros_mpu9150/mpu9150_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ros_mpu9150/CMakeFiles/mpu9150_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

These `undefined reference to` refer to functions declared in `mpu9150.h` and `linux_glue.h`. But these headers should be visible due to the `include_directories` step, right?. Also, libraries are being added in the `target_link_libraries` step.
Or that's what i thought because if i substitute:

```
target_link_libraries(mpu9150_node mpu9150 inv_mpu quaternion linux_glue inv_mpu_dmp_motion_driver vector3d ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

for:

```
target_link_libraries(mpu9150_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I get the exact same result.
I recently started getting familiar with CMakeLists. Anybody could share some ideas?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69775/ros-mpu9150:-cmakelists.txt-undefined-reference/) by [v.mayoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/4008/v.mayoral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a ROS or cmake error, but originates from the linker - so your code.

First the obvious: Do these functions exist like that in your code? Are they also compiled into object files somewhere (not just included in a header)? And are these object files linked into the main executable or into a library that is linked to that?

Given those are true I suspect you are mixing C and C++ code and have a name mangling issue. Is the header with the respective functions used both in .c and .cpp files? In that case use the usual

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
....
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

before and after your function declarations in the header.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v.mayoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/4008/v.mayoral/) on 2013-07-30**:
Thanks dornhege. That was it, i needed the `extern "C" ...`.